# Возврат к первому элементу списка в цикле

Tags: python, list

Есть список из 4 элементов listProxy:

> ['10.204.7.121', '10.204.7.122', '10.204.7.123', '10.204.7.124']

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в цикле while при достижении последнего элемента в списке listProxy брался снова первый элемент

```
ii = 0
while ii < 10:
    print(listProxy[ii])
    ii = ii + 1
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: `print(listProxy[ii%len(listProxy)])`

Comment: Благодарю. То, что нужно. Напишите в ответ и я отмечу вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя остаток от деления на длину списка - мы всегда будем получать числа (индексы) в диапазоне: `0` ... `list_length - 1`.

Пример:

```
In [44]: ii = 0
    ...: while ii < 10:
    ...:     print('ii: {}'.format(ii), 'ii%len(listProxy): {}'.format(ii%len(listProxy)), listProxy[ii%len(listProxy)])
    ...:     ii = ii + 1
    ...:
ii: 0 ii%len(listProxy): 0 10.204.7.121
ii: 1 ii%len(listProxy): 1 10.204.7.122
ii: 2 ii%len(listProxy): 2 10.204.7.123
ii: 3 ii%len(listProxy): 3 10.204.7.124
ii: 4 ii%len(listProxy): 0 10.204.7.121
ii: 5 ii%len(listProxy): 1 10.204.7.122
ii: 6 ii%len(listProxy): 2 10.204.7.123
ii: 7 ii%len(listProxy): 3 10.204.7.124
ii: 8 ii%len(listProxy): 0 10.204.7.121
ii: 9 ii%len(listProxy): 1 10.204.7.122
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то цикл по индексам в Питоне наводит на мысль, что код не в питон-стиле, так что предложу свое решение:

```
import itertools

listProxy = ['10.204.7.121', '10.204.7.122', '10.204.7.123', '10.204.7.124']
for proxy, _ in zip(itertools.cycle(listProxy), range(10)):
    print(proxy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо обращения по индексам, более идиоматично в Питоне сразу элементы списка получить, используя обычный for-цикл.
Используя [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), можно по кругу до бесконечности элементы перебирать:

```
import itertools 

for proxy in itertools.cycle(proxies):
    print(proxy)
```

`proxies` здесь вместо `listProxy` используется.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = itertools.cycle(listProxy)
while True:
    print(next(i))
```